# Postman API Post request

Tags: rest, postman

If the response looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/360ee.jpg), how do I construct the right post call?
When I enter this as raw data in the post call for the same ip-adress I can an internal server error.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean here. Do you mean that this is the response for a GET request? How do you know that the given API route can handle POST requests?

Comment: Yes, this is a response for a GET call. The documentation says that there is a post call for this function.

Comment: You might need to tell the server what the `Content-Type` of your data is. Possibly something like `Content-Type: application\json`. This can be added in the **Headers** section of the POST request. I know that's been a problem for me before. Does the documentation specify any headers you need to give in addition to the body of the request?

Comment: unfortunately not, my actual task is to post from a unity project with c# and there I already defined the header and I still got the same problem.

Comment: Are you POSTing to something called Cognition Factory? I found this: http://doc.cognitionfactory.eu/r0/_modules/r0/server/httpserver.html

Comment: If I'm reading the handler for `/present/effector_position.json` correctly, it looks like it expects something like: `{"x": 1, "y": 1, "z": 1, "duration": 1, "wait": true}`. Furthermore, I think the `wait` option is optional.

Comment: I tried it: http://imgur.com/C9J0ljY Still the same error

Comment: Sorry, I guess I don't know then. It might be helpful if you can show exactly what the error is too.

Comment: Internal Server Error, or what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry the requested URL caused an error